# Analysis - Fourier Transforms - show that convolution of characteristic functions is continuous

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I would appreciate any instruction on the following exercise from real and complex analysis:

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are measurable subsets of $\Re^1$, having finite positive measure.  Show that the convolution $\chi_A * \chi_B$ is continuous and not identically zero.  Use this to prove that $A + B$ contains a segment.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The second part of your question is a variation of Steinhaus' theorem. This has surely been proved many times here on MSE.

Answer (score 1):

- By inner-regularity of Lebesgue measure, we are reduced to the case where $A$ is a compact subset of finite positive measure.
- We can approximate the characteristic function of such a set monotonically and pointwise by a continuous function with compact support.